# Is there a cdn for Brick?

Tags: mozilla-brick

It looks like [Mozilla's brick](http://mozilla.github.io/brick/) is going to be updated constantly.

Q: Is there a cdn for brick?

Answer (score 1):

From official site of brick: To include Brick in your project, include your **downloaded** stylesheet and script files in your project's page like normal:

Also I researched and there is not anything about cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="brick-1.0.0.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="brick-1.0.0.js"></script>
```